# Best practice for transfering MSSQL Databases and all accounts to new server?

Tags: sql-server

One of our customers has installed a new SQL server and needs to take down the old SQL box. Both servers are running Microsoft SQL Server 2008. The applications all access the current SQL server via hostname so the plan is to transfer everything then cut over the connections by updating DNS.

My question is: "What is the best way to actually move the databases and all associated accounts to the new server?"

Nothing about the current set up is documented. I need to figure out how to move over all the databases, stored procedures, SQL agent jobs, and SQL authentication accounts to the new server (note: the only account password I have is the sa password).

I am not a MSSQL guru so any help would be appreciated. Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess a `Backup/Restore` would be appropriate here.

**Update:**

- If you additionally need *logins* to be transferred, use:
  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992/en-us
- If you need *all database objects* to be transferred, use the [Copy Database Wizard](http://sql-articles.com/articles/dba/how-to-use-copy-database-wizard/) instead of *Backup/Restore*

Comment: The backup/restore feature would handle the databases themselves but not the security settings, accounts, agent jobs, etc...

Comment: You can transfer logins by using: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992/en-us
Not sure about the security settings/agent jobs

Comment: The Database copy wizard seems to be able to copy all associated objects: http://sql-articles.com/articles/dba/how-to-use-copy-database-wizard/

Comment: +1 +1. Thanks guys. Don't know how I missed that KB article and the blog post is a nice find too.

Comment: I've added those the answer. Glad I could help out.